# React native project won't start windows

Tags: react-native

I have created a new React Native project using `npx react-native ProjectName`. When trying to start it with `react run android`, the Metro bundler starts but after a second it closes without displaying any error. This project was created with WebStorm that displayed in the project creation dialog that it used v2.0.1 of the cli.

I saw on github that this is a known bug of this version so I created another project manually with `npx react-native@latest`, but without any result.

Also, when trying to start the project with `npm start` I get this error:

`Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.`

Any suggestions?

Comment: try with react-native run-android

Comment: Well, react run android is the script the npm script that points to react-native run-android